# print ReportViewer from custom button not toolbar

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, printing, reportviewer

Ok I've spent a few hours(4 to be exact) looking for a solution to this.  I've found a couple of results but none work so far. :(

Issue: I have a reportviewer in a usercontrol and I hid the toolbar and created my own.  Now I added a button that is supposed to print, but can't seem to get it to work.  I'll take any solutions you all may have for me.  But it has to be a button no the default bar that comes with the report.

Here's my code:

```
<rsweb:reportviewer 
ID="rvReports" 
runat="server" 
Height="600px"
Width="600px"
ShowToolBar="False"
SizeToReportContent="True" AsyncRendering="false" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnprint" runat="server" ImageUrl="../img/print.png" 
     OnClientClick="PrintReport();" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintReport() {
    var viewerReference = $find("rvReports");
    var reportArea = viewerReference.get_reportAreaContentType();
        if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) {
            $find("rvReports").invokePrintDialog();
        }

 } 
</script>
```

the error I get with this is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get_reportAreaContentType' of null
```

Just in case I added a Jquery Library cause I thought that was it but nothing doing..
BTW I got that javascript from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2011/04/09/invoking-the-print-dialog-for-report-viewer-2010-control-using-the-javascript-api.aspx) as it was one of the answers on another stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Your title says "from codebehind" (server side C# code), but sample has only JavaScript client side code. Which one is correct (please update question/title if needed).

Comment: there you go, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using ITextSharp for this, it was quite simple.  Add a hidden iframe and in codebehind this:

```
Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;

        byte[] bytes = rvReports.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType,
                       out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();

        //Open exsisting pdf
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER_LANDSCAPE, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"));
        //Getting a instance of new pdf wrtiter
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(
           HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Print.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        int i = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

        //float width = psize.Width;
        //float height = psize.Height;

        //Add Page to new document
        while (i < n)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            p++;
            i++;

            PdfImportedPage page1 = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            cb.AddTemplate(page1, 0, 0);
        }

        //Attach javascript to the document
        PdfAction jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
        writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);
        document.Close();

        //Attach pdf to the iframe
        frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = "Print.pdf";
```

and that did it, guess just had to keep digging inside google..lol

Answer (score 0):

From the error it look like `$find("rvReports")` returns collection with no controls and as result get_reportAreaContentType reports an error. Check in script debugger what is result of the `$find("rvReports")` call and see if element you expect is present in the view.

Note I think selector should be "#rvReports"...

Answer (score 0):

Use clientId not serverId in the $find function:

```
$find(<%=rvReports.ClientID%>)
```